# how to find position after search word into string then mark this

Tags: php, arrays

I'm going to find desired word in a string, and then I show Mark or highlight

```
$str = "this is a test for testing a test function";

$array = explode(' ',$str);
$key = array_search('tes', $array);

$tr='';
foreach($array as $i=>$ar){
    if($key == $i){
        $tr .= '<a style="color:red">'.$ar.'</a> '; 
    }else{
        $tr .= $ar.' ';     
    }
}
echo $tr;//this is a <a style="color:red">test</a> for <a style="color:red">testing</a> a <a style="color:red">test</a> function
```

search -> 'tes';
echo after find -> this is a "test" for "testing" a "test" function

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Why not just `str_replace('tes', '<strong>tes</strong>', $str)`?

Comment: Any occurrence of `tes` should become a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$term="testing a test";
function search_array($array, $term)
{       
    $keys=array();
    foreach ($array AS $key => $value) {
        $term1 = explode(' ',$term);
        foreach ($term1 AS $k => $t) {
            if (stristr($value, $t) === FALSE) {
                continue;
            } else {
                $keys[]=$key;
            }
        }
    }

    return $keys;
}
$str = "this is a test for testing a test function"; 
$array = explode(' ',$str);
$data=search_array($array, $term); //get keys
$tr='';
foreach($array as $i=>$ar){
    if(in_array($i,$data)){//if avialable
        $tr .= '<a style="color:red">'.$ar.'</a> '; 
    }else{
        $tr .= $ar.' ';     
    }
}
echo $tr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems complicated. You don't have to split the whole text to do the replacement:

```
$str = "this is a test for testing a test function";
$search = "tes";
echo str_replace($search, "<strong>$search</strong>", $str);
```

If you just want to search for whole words, regular expressions might help you:

```
$search = "test";
$regex = "~\b(" . preg_quote($search, '~') . ")\b~";
echo preg_replace($regex, "<strong>$1</strong>", $str);
```

Comment: (search -> tes )                                                                                           (echo -> this is a "test" for "testing" a "test" function)

Comment: This is a better approach, I don't think the OP wants the word boundaries though. Looks like the `tes` is just the intro. I think `(\S*tes\S*)` would be what the OP needs.

Comment: @user3445955 what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 $str = "this is a test for testing a test function";        
    function search_array($array, $term)
    {
        $keys=array();
        foreach ($array AS $key => $value) {
            if (stristr($value, $term) === FALSE) {
                continue;
            } else {
                $keys[]=$key;
            }
        }
        return $keys;
    }

   $array = explode(' ',$str);
    $term="tes";
    $data=search_array($array, $term); //get keys
    $tr='';
    foreach($array as $i=>$ar){
        if(in_array($i,$data)){//if avialable
            $tr .= '<a style="color:red">'.$ar.'</a> '; 
        }else{
            $tr .= $ar.' ';     
        }
    }
    echo $tr;
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c7404f7e9b065f13592e7f402aa13f4dc60d44a)

Comment: @user3445955 because in the above approach they are different array elements not a single.

Comment: @user3445955 if your string is fixed you can use.http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a0631c0348fd3fc89d3a1e83c8a48547d9548850